# Dropping the column with Default value tied to custom data type

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints, custom-data-type

I am in SQL Server.
I have to drop a column 'colA' from the table 'tblA'

```
- Column is of type 'myType' - custom datatype.  That custom datatype has its 
  own default value - that we call 'DefaultZero'
- There are many tables with columns of this custom datatype.
```

When I try to drop the column, I get the error message

```
The object 'DefaultZero' is dependent on column 'colA'.
```

I understand that I have to "somehow" remove that dependency, but I do not know.

```
I am NOT to delete the custom datatype.  
I am NOT to remove the DefaultZero object.
```

I sort of sense there may be something in some of the system tables under the system schema, but I do not know what to look for.  Can anyone help ?

Comment: smells like a foreign key constraint

Comment: @scsimon You have a strong sense of smell :)

Comment: That 'DefaultZero' is not under 'Keys' nor it is under 'Constraints' in the object explorer

Comment: it doesn't have to be named that, but that doesn't mean it isn't one.

Comment: `sp_unbindefault` might help. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-unbindefault-transact-sql

Comment: Thank you !!!  sp_unbindefault  is exactly what I was looking for.  Perfect !!!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @WEI_DBA
The answer is sp_unbindefault

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-unbindefault-transact-sql